# Will Thread.setPriority have any impact unless the underlying OS supports preemptive multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

According to my understanding(which may be incorrect. Kindly correct me if it is so), thread scheduler(or thread dispatcher) is the one who will decide which thread gets the CPU time (when multiple threads are competing for the CPU). This thread scheduler is OS dependent. Thread scheduler can use either time slicing algorithm or preemptive algorithm or something else. If the underlying OS's thread scheduler uses time slicing algorithm, then setting high/low priority for a thread using JAVA's Thread.setHightPriority() method will have any impact at all ?

If yes, then how can it make an impact on the underlying OS's thread scheduler ?
If not, then what is the point of having Thread.setPriority() method in this case ? Should the java developer be aware of on which OS this application will be running and if that OS uses preemptive multithreading then only go for Thread.setPriority() ?

Any thoughts on this is much appreciated ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If the underlying OS's thread scheduler uses time slicing algorithm, then setting high/low priority for a thread using JAVA's Thread.setHightPriority() method will have any impact at all ?

Yes. Why do you think it won't?

> If yes, then how can it make an impact on the underlying OS's thread scheduler?

Because time slices can still be allocated in priority order. You seem to be assuming this is impossible. Why?

> Should the java developer be aware of on which OS this application will be running and if that OS uses preemptive multithreading then only go for Thread.setPriority() ?

No, and you haven't disclosed your actual reasons for thinking otherwise.

Comment: Are you saying, if high priority is set for a thread, then this thread will get the CPU time first among other competing threads in time slicing algorithm. If so, what happens when this high priority thread blocks on some user input and other low priority thread kicks in ? Even if the high priority thread is unblocked, should not it wait till the other low priority threads get their CPU time according to the time slicing algo. If it is a preemptive multithreading, then when the high priority thread is unblocked, it can preempt the low priority ones. Is not it ?

Comment: 1. Yes, of course, otherwise priority has no meaning at all. 2. The blocked thread blocks and another thread is scheduled. 3. Yes, if time-slicing is all there is. 4. Yes, pre-emptive means pre-emptive.

Comment: That means, as a JAVA developer, when I used the java API, the behavior is not consistent across platforms. If I want to make sure that high priority thread always gets the high priority(irrespective of whether it has come back from blocked state or not etc.) using Thread.setPriority() is not guaranteeing me the correct behavior on all platforms. It is dependent on the platform. Is not it ? That is why in my last question I asked whether java developer should be aware of the underlying platform in which it runs to use setPriority for the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, priorities are only hints to the scheduler, they cannot be relied upon.

> Every thread has a priority. When there is competition for processing
>   resources, threads with higher priority are generally executed in
>   preference to threads with lower priority. **Such preference is not,
>   however, a guarantee that the highest priority thread will always be
>   running**, and thread priorities cannot be used to reliably implement
>   mutual exclusion.

- from the *Java Language Specification (2nd Edition)* p.445.

Also ...

> Although thread priorities exist in Java and many references state
>   that the JVM will always select one of the highest priority threads
>   for scheduling [52, 56, 89], this is currently not guaranteed by the
>   Java language or virtual machine specifications [53, 90]. **Priorities
>   are only hints to the scheduler** [127, page 227].

- from *Testing Concurrent Java Components (PhD Thesis, 2005)* p. 62.
- Reference 127, page 227 (from the excerpt above) is from *Component Software: Beyond Object-Oriented Programming (by C. Szyperski), Addison Wesley, 1998.*

In short, **do not rely on thread priorities**.